# Symfony doctrine many to one relation with embedded form collection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 2 entities : **Doctor** & **Timetable**  where one doctor has many timetables(OneToMany)  and many timetables have one doctor(ManyToOne).I want to create many timetables from Doctor Create form Screen. So, i followed the article [embedded form collection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)
Everything is working fine except that **I am getting the doctors dropdown on timetable create session which means I can only create timetable for existing doctors.** I know that the doctors dropdown came from ManyToOne relationships.
But for my case, I need to create timetable for current doctor(the one that gonna create on the screen) without choosing the dropdown of existing doctors. To tell the logic what I want with pseudo codes:

```
//Doctor Create Action 
        public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new Doctor();
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

      // Save(Persist) Doctor   
      // Grab Newly Created Doctor ID
      // Create Timetables  with that Doctor ID
      // done   
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

I have read all similar questions but no solution for me. Please anyone help me with some example that symfony beginner can understand.Thank you.

Below is the table structures & related codes :

**Doctor Entity Table**

id             INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
  name        VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL

**Timetable Entity Table** 
  id                                INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT 
  doctor_id            INT *(foreign key to doctor)* 
  clinic_id               INT *(foreign key to clinic)* 
  _time                       VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL

**Doctor Entity Class**

```
<?php

namespace Nay\MMClinicsBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * Doctor
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="doctors")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Nay\MMClinicsBundle\Entity\DoctorRepository")
 */

class Doctor
{



/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Timetable", mappedBy="doctor", cascade={"persist"})
 */
public $timetables;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="doctor_name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $doctorName;



public function __construct(){
    $this->timetables = new ArrayCollection();

}


/**
*get timetable of this doctor
* @return arraycollection
*/
public function getTimetables(){
    return $this->timetables;
}

public function addTimetable(Timetable $t)
{
    $this->timetables->add($t);
}

public function removeTimetable(Timetable $t)
{
    $this->timetables->removeElement($t);
}


        // **setters & getters for each property here** 


}
```

**Timetable Entity Class**

```
<?php

namespace Nay\MMClinicsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Timetable
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="timetables")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Nay\MMClinicsBundle\Entity\TimetableRepository")
 */
class Timetable
{

/**
 * @var Clinic
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Clinic", inversedBy="timetables")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="clinic_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
public $clinic;

/**
 * @var Doctor
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Doctor", inversedBy="timetables")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="doctor_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
public $doctor;


/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="clinic_id", type="integer")
 */
private $clinicId;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="doctor_id", type="integer")
 */
private $doctorId;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="_time", type="string", length=1024)
 */
private $time;


  //**setters & getters for each property here** 

}
```

**Doctor Form Type**

```
    /**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('doctorName')
        ->add('timetables', 'collection', array('type' => new TimetableType(),'allow_add' => true ,'by_reference' => false, 'allow_delete' => true ));
    ;
}
```

**Timetable Form Type**

```
<?php

namespace Nay\MMClinicsBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class TimetableType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('clinic')
            ->add('doctor')
            ->add('time','text',array('attr'=>array("data-role"=>"tagsinput")))
        ;
    }

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Nay\MMClinicsBundle\Entity\Timetable'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'nay_mmclinicsbundle_timetable';
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the "current" doctor you are interested with, is the one that had actually logged into the system? Meaning, we can replace the dropdown with just this one.

Comment: sorry, the current doctor is the one that current form screen gonna create.(assumed the user is creating a doctor and creating timetables from doctor create form)

Comment: doctor is the content, not user actually.

Comment: can you please tell me what is in your TimetableFormType.php?

Comment: @herr i have added my timetable form type. i currently solved the situation my using  lifecycle events  prepersist, postpersist etc. and hiding the doctor dropdown field from timetable form. but i am not sure this is recommended way.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-3480

http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-3556

> Mention that only basic mapping is supported by embeddables

So, ManyToOne with Embedded still not supported by Doctrine 2, it's a pity.

Answer (score 0):

Even I am not sure this way is recommended. but I had solved it in following way. 
First remove the following line from timetable form type:

```
->add('doctor')
```

In your controller createAction() add this code after your doctor entity save/flush.

```
$doctor = $form->getData();
if($doctor->getTimetables())
{
     foreach ($doctor->getTimetables() as $timetable) {
           $timetable->setDoctor($doctor);
           $em->persist($timetable);
           $em->flush();
     }
}
```

In your controller updateAction() add this code befor your form handleRequest.

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:Doctor')->find($id);
$originalTimetables = new ArrayCollection();
if($entity->getTimetables())
{
     foreach ($entity->getTimetables() as $timetable) {
          $originalTimetables->add($timetable);
     }
}
```

In your controller updateAction() add this code after your form handleRequest and before doctor entity flush.

```
$editForm->handleRequest($request);
if ($editForm->isValid()) {
   foreach ($originalTimetables as $timetable) 
   {
       if (false == $entity->getTimetables()->contains($timetable)) 
       {     
           $timetable->getDoctor()->removeTimetable($timetable);
           $em->remove($timetable);
           $em->flush();
       }
   }
   $em->flush();
```

In your controller updateAction() add this code after your doctor entity flush.

```
   $doctor = $editForm->getData();
   if($doctor->getTimetables())
   {
        foreach ($doctor->getTimetables() as $timetable) 
        {
           $timetable->setDoctor($doctor);
           $em->flush();
        }
   }
}
```

I am not sure and even not tried $em->flush() will required in each loop or will work out side of loop only once it will work. :)

Comment: thank you for the answer.  if i am not wrong, doctrine automatically save the entity and its associations(timetables in this case) already on $em->persist($entity); , $em->flush(); .so, would it be extra work or duplicate save to do like that ?

Comment: In my way of logic i am removing ->add('doctor') from timetableFormType so it is required to do this extra work only for set doctor(id) in timetable entry $timetable->setDoctor($doctor); I think your way is may right. but i do this is just removing doctor dropdown from form :)